# Get Azure key vault secret using Ansible - how can I tell azure_preview_modules in Ansible script where the correct Ansible is installed?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ansible, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to get an Ansible playbook to be able to read a secret in an Azure key vault, as per this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/key-vault-configure-secrets?tabs=ansible#get-secrets-from-key-vault. It seems so simple. My Playbook is the following:

```
---
- name: key vault testing
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  roles: 
    -  { role: azure.azure_preview_modules }

  vars:
    tenant_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    vault_name: xxxxxxxxx
    secret_name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    client_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    client_secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

  tasks:
  - name: Get Key Vault by name
    azure_rm_keyvault_info:
      resource_group: xxxxxxxxxx
      name: "{{ vault_name }}"
    register: keyvault

  - name: Set key vault URI fact
    set_fact: keyvaulturi="{{ keyvault['keyvaults'][0]['vault_uri'] }}"

  - name: Set key vault secret fact
    set_fact: secretValue={{ lookup('azure_keyvault_secret',secret_name,vault_url=keyvaulturi, client_id=client_id, secret=client_secret, tenant_id=tenant_id) }}

  - name: Output key vault secret
    debug:
      msg: "{{ secretValue }}"
```

When I run this, I get the following output/error:

```
PLAY [key vault testing] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [azure.azure_preview_modules : Install Azure Python SDK required by modules.] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [azure.azure_preview_modules : debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Your Ansible version is lower than 2.5.0",
        "You may need to perform additional steps to install this roles:",
        "  sudo pip install -r /home/administrator/.ansible/roles/azure.azure_preview_modules/files/requirements-azure.txt",
        "or",
        "  pip install --user -r /home/administrator/.ansible/roles/azure.azure_preview_modules/files/requirements-azure.txt",
        "depending on your ansible setup."
    ]
}

TASK [Get Key Vault by name] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: AnsibleModule.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check_invalid_arguments'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/administrator/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1660655181.949111-2808-175135597436300/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_keyvault_info.py\", line 107, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/administrator/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1660655181.949111-2808-175135597436300/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_keyvault_info.py\", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/administrator/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1660655181.949111-2808-175135597436300/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_keyvault_info.py\", line 47, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.azure_rm_keyvault_info', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible.modules.azure_rm_keyvault_info', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 209, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 86, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_keyvault_info_payload_7xtlk5_l/ansible_azure_rm_keyvault_info_payload.zip/ansible/modules/azure_rm_keyvault_info.py\", line 323, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_keyvault_info_payload_7xtlk5_l/ansible_azure_rm_keyvault_info_payload.zip/ansible/modules/azure_rm_keyvault_info.py\", line 319, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_keyvault_info_payload_7xtlk5_l/ansible_azure_rm_keyvault_info_payload.zip/ansible/modules/azure_rm_keyvault_info.py\", line 227, in __init__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_keyvault_info_payload_7xtlk5_l/ansible_azure_rm_keyvault_info_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 288, in __init__\nTypeError: AnsibleModule.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check_invalid_arguments'\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 installed in Hyper-V, and I followed the Ansible installation instructions here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html. I'm able to run other Ansible playbooks fine. I have installed azure_preview_modules with `ansible-galaxy install azure.azure_preview_modules`. I think my error might be around this part:

```
"Your Ansible version is lower than 2.5.0"
```

If I run `ansible --version` I get this output:

```
ansible [core 2.13.3]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/administrator/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/administrator/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/administrator/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/administrator/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.4 (main, Jun 29 2022, 12:14:53) [GCC 11.2.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

This tells me that my Ansible version is not lower than 2.5.0, and that's why I think this is where I should start looking. Does anybody have any ideas I could try? I'm just about ready to pull all of my hair out!!!
Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

> TASK [azure.azure_preview_modules : debug] * ok: [localhost] => {
> "msg": [
> "Your Ansible version is lower than 2.5.0",
> "You may need to perform additional steps to install this roles:",  An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full

The above error occurs due to your `ansible-galaxy install azure.azure_preview_modules` is 2.5.0 in the playbook

Usually playbook:

> Multiple collections may have modules which can have same name  (for example, `user`) so In Ansible 2.10 and later please make sure to use the fully-qualified collection name in your playbooks so that correct module is selected.

The playbook may not be able to process with your arguments below the ansible ***version 2.10***

Possible conditions to resolve :

- Uninstall the Ansible

  `sudo apt remove ansible`
- Install the Ansible using pip

  `pip3 install ansible`
- Install the system-wide apt

  `sudo apt install ansible`

Reference:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the response Venkatesan.S-MT

So, I have azure.azure_preview_modules (2.9.1) installed, so I know that this isn't the thing that is below 2.5.0 in the playbook.

Also, thanks for your suggestion of re-installing Ansible system-wide. I tried it, and am still getting the same results. I think the best thing to do right now is to first identify the preferred method of doing this, as there are multiple ways documented on the internet.